# Stop Parts from being detachable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to stop `Parts` from being detachable in Eclipse RCP 4.

Currently if I right click on a `Part` I can select detach. From this I can then close the tab even if the `Part` isn't `Closeable`. In RCP 3 when a detached `View` is closed it would then return back to its original location but now it closes completely.

**Structure**

[image]

**Part Config**

[image]

How can I remove the option to detach a `Part`?

Also how can I stop a detached `Part` from being closed or make it return to its original location?

Comment: To remove the menu option you would have to override the stack renderer to do this - which is fairly straightforward except that you have to duplicate some of the existing code. The other option is to not persist the application model and always start with the original design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop parts being detachable I used a custom stack renderer and overrode the method to populate the tab menu.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTRenderersMessages;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;

public class UndetachableStackRenderer extends StackRenderer
{
    @Inject 
    private IEclipseContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() 
    {
        super.init(context);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void populateTabMenu(final Menu menu, final MPart part)
    {
        super.populateTabMenu(menu, part);

        final MenuItem[] menuItems = menu.getItems();

        final Optional<MenuItem> detachMenuItem = Arrays.stream(menuItems).filter(item -> item.getText().equals(SWTRenderersMessages.menuDetach)).findFirst();

        if(detachMenuItem.isPresent())
        {
            detachMenuItem.get().dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I then added a `Persisted State` into the Part Stacks that I didn't want to show the `Detach` option.

If anybody is having trouble setting a custom stack renderer then my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572702/adding-a-custom-renderer-to-different-parts) might help.

Comment: Must call `super.init()` in `init` method, otherwise the inject method that depended on this   PartStack will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the bug :  [Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357289)

I think you have to wait for the fix for `NoDetach` till it is available

For time being you can use  `NoMove` tag which can stop dnd

[Documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Modeled_UI/Tags)

A part can be annotated with a `NoMove` tag to indicate that the drag-and-drop system should not allow the user to move this part. (Defined by IPresentationEngine.NO_MOVE)

[image: <code>Image</code>]

Comment: To my understanding, the`NoDetach`tag should work in eclipse 2018-12.. but it does not work for me

Comment: `NoDetach` stops the view from being dragged out of the main window and detaching. It doesn't stop the user from right clicking the view and clicking `Detach` though..