# Adding a custom renderer to different parts

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I would like some parts to use a different renderer. In some cases I would like to remove the `Detach` option when right clicking and this is a solution according to a comment on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205912/stop-parts-from-being-detachable).

I've been following [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) tutorial as to how this can be done.

I've created two classes. `UndetachableStackRenderer` and `UndetachableStackRendererFactory`.

If I add `UndetachableStackRendererFactory` to the `plugin.xml` it successfully removes the option to detach from **ALL** part stacks.

```
<property
    name="rendererFactoryUri"
    value="bundleclass://com.example.loc/com.example.loc.UndetachableStackRendererFactory">
</property>
```

I would instead like to change the renderer for one part stack. According to the tutorial I can add `CUSTOM_RENDERER_URI` to the `Persisted State` of the part stack.

Key:

```
CUSTOM_RENDERER_URI
```

Value:

`bundleclass://com.example.loc/com.example.loc.UndetachableStackRenderer`

I've tried this and it does nothing. If I enter an incorrect location it doesn't come up with any errors either so it seems as though `CUSTOM_RENDERER_URI` isn't being seen.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial seems to be wrong, at least for the current Eclipse release.

The key value is defined in `IPresentationEngine.CUSTOM_RENDERER_KEY` and has the value `Custom Renderer`

```
String CUSTOM_RENDERER_KEY = "Custom Renderer";
```

It is used in the `getRenderer` method of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine`

Comment: This worked perfectly on Windows but we have noticed that on Mac all of the views are empty and no errors are output. The only changes I've made are adding the `persistedState` of `Custom Renderer` and `UndetachableStackRenderer` as displayed above. Are there any known issues for this as I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: I don't use this way of defining a renderer so I don't know. You can always search Eclipse [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced).  The renderer factory method does work fine on macOS.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of defining a renderer? This is strange. I'll have a look.